# Is there a standard technique or API for getting the site header image?

Tags: options, settings-api, header-image

There is this function:

[get_header_image()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header_image/)

which can be called from within WordPress. Is there a way to access this externally, i.e. from the API? The use case might be a header for an external RSS feed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

All the out-of-the-box API endpoints are documented quite well here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/

A quick look in the relevant places didn't turn up a way to get theme elements (although I might have missed it).

It's trivially easy to setup new API endpoints; here's a quick example you could pop into your funcitons.php to 'hard-wire' into that function to allow you to get the result returned in JSON at `example.com/wp-json/themeelements/v1/header_image`:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'themeelements/v1', '/header_image', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_header_image',
  ) );
} );
```

(Note for me with a clean WP install and the twentytwenty theme with no images added this returns an empty string)